# google drive import xml log in

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I try to import some data from a secure site with sigh into a spreadsheet in Google Drive.

I can retrieve information like the title or some menus, but the private content returns #N/A value.

I have this chunk of html, and i need to get the Issues:

```
<div class="gh-box-section">
<ul class="gh-ul-aa">
 <li>
  <div class="gh-group">
    <em>Bug:</em> 37
  </div>
 </li>
 <li class="gh-summary">
  <div class="gh-group">
   <em>Total Issues:</em> 37
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I guess I can not get the sensitive information for some permission or login, I try to retrieve the information opening my session in one Chrome tab and make the import in another tab, but it did not work.

so, my question: is there a way to start a session for another site from Google Drive and import sensitive data from the html code?

Comment: Possible solutions depend on what form of authentication is supported by the target site. What can you tell about that? (See [these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=urlfetchapp+password+[google-apps-script]) for some ideas.)